# C++ Visual Studio 2013 Unwinding object

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, try-catch

Well, I'm trying to build this line of code, bit I get a compiler error. I've tryed to build without the compiler, but that didn't work either. Its about the `__try` and `__except`. Someone told me to move the code in the try block to another function. But I don't understand this:

> Error 12  error C2712: Cannot use __try in functions that require
>   object unwinding
>
> Error 437 error LNK1181: cannot open input file

```
void MSocketThread::Run()
{
    __try{
        //throw(pThread);
        while (true) {  // Waiting for SafeUDP Settting...
            DWORD dwVal = WaitForSingleObject(m_KillEvent.GetEvent(), 100);
            if (dwVal == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
                return;
            }
            else if (dwVal == WAIT_TIMEOUT) {
                if (m_pSafeUDP)
                    break;
            }
        }

    WSAEVENT EventArray[WSA_MAXIMUM_WAIT_EVENTS];
    WORD wEventIndex = 0;

    bool bSendable = false;
    WSANETWORKEVENTS NetEvent;
    WSAEVENT hFDEvent = WSACreateEvent();
    EventArray[wEventIndex++] = hFDEvent;
    EventArray[wEventIndex++] = m_ACKEvent.GetEvent();
    EventArray[wEventIndex++] = m_SendEvent.GetEvent();
    EventArray[wEventIndex++] = m_KillEvent.GetEvent();

    WSAEventSelect(m_pSafeUDP->GetLocalSocket(), hFDEvent, FD_READ | FD_WRITE);

    while (TRUE) {
        DWORD dwReturn = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(wEventIndex, EventArray, FALSE, SAFEUDP_SAFE_MANAGE_TIME, FALSE);
        if (dwReturn == WSA_WAIT_TIMEOUT) {                 // Time
            m_pSafeUDP->LockNetLink();
            SafeSendManage();
            m_pSafeUDP->UnlockNetLink();
        }
        else if (dwReturn == WSA_WAIT_EVENT_0) {            // Socket Event
            WSAEnumNetworkEvents(m_pSafeUDP->GetLocalSocket(), hFDEvent, &NetEvent);
            if ((NetEvent.lNetworkEvents & FD_READ) == FD_READ) {
                //              OutputDebugString("SUDP> FD_READ \n");
                m_pSafeUDP->LockNetLink();
                Recv();
                m_pSafeUDP->UnlockNetLink();
            }
            if ((NetEvent.lNetworkEvents & FD_WRITE) == FD_WRITE) {
                bSendable = true;
                //              OutputDebugString("SUDP> FD_WRITE \n");
            }
        }
        else if (dwReturn == WSA_WAIT_EVENT_0 + 1) {        // ACK Send Event
            //          OutputDebugString("SUDP> ACK_EVENT \n");
            FlushACK();
        }
        else if (dwReturn == WSA_WAIT_EVENT_0 + 2) {        // Packet Send Event
            //          OutputDebugString("SUDP> SEND_EVENT \n");
            if (bSendable == true)
                FlushSend();
        }
        else if (dwReturn == WSA_WAIT_EVENT_0 + 3) {        // Kill the Thread
            break;  // Stop Thread
        }
    }

    WSACloseEvent(hFDEvent);

    // Clear Queues
    LockSend();
    {
        for (SendListItor itor = m_SendList.begin(); itor != m_SendList.end();) {
            delete (*itor);
            itor = m_SendList.erase(itor);
        }
    }
    {
        for (SendListItor itor = m_TempSendList.begin(); itor != m_TempSendList.end();) {
            delete (*itor);
            itor = m_TempSendList.erase(itor);
        }
    }
    UnlockSend();

    LockACK();
    {
        for (ACKSendListItor itor = m_ACKSendList.begin(); itor != m_ACKSendList.end();) {
            delete (*itor);
            itor = m_ACKSendList.erase(itor);
        }
    }
    {
        for (ACKSendListItor itor = m_TempACKSendList.begin(); itor != m_TempACKSendList.end();) {
            delete (*itor);
            itor = m_TempACKSendList.erase(itor);
        }
    }
    UnlockACK();
}
__except (this->CrashDump(GetExceptionInformation()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, SEH and C++ unwinding aren't exactly compatible; they require the compiler to modify the function on the machine code level, and MS apparently decided not to support the modifications for the two at the same time, so any function can only support either SEH unwind actions (__except or __finally) or C++ unwind actions (catch or objects with destructors).

I suspect the problem in your case are the iterators in your loops; they might have destructors. Although iterators are usually simple and don't need destructors, this is not the case for debug iterators, which often register their existence on construction and deregister it on destruction, in order to detect invalidated iterators and other invalid usage.

The usual workaround is to split the function. Make your run function contain just this:

```
void MSocketThread::Run()
{
    __try {
      RunNoSeh();
    } __except (this->CrashDump(GetExceptionInformation())) {
    }
}
void MSocketThread::RunNoSeh()
{
    // Code that was inside the __try goes here.
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I get a bunch of errors, could you post the full code?

Comment: The full code of what? I just copied parts of the code you posted.

Comment: If I add your code lines I get a bunch of errors, like, is undifined and code lines in the full .cpp file doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Did you add a declaration for `RunNoSeh` to the class definition? I assume you have a basic knowledge of how C++ works here.

Comment: Yes, I have only a basic knowledge of how C++ works, what would be the code line for the class definition?

Comment: Add `void RunNoSeh();` to the private section of your class.

Comment: I have no private section or class?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not going to babysit your every keystroke here. Make some effort; the information you need is in every basic C++ tutorial.